Custom color for a specific tile in a heatmap
I have a 2D heatmap that represents the sample space of two four-sided dice. That is, the possible values of the sum of the two dices after being tossed. The code is presented below:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.16}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap = {custom}{color(0)=(nblue!20) color(1)=(nblue!30) color(2)=(nblue!40) color(3)=(nblue!50) color(4)=(nblue!60) color(5)=(nblue!70) color(6)=(nblue!80) color(7)=(nblue!90) color(8)=(nblue)
        },
        xlabel={$X$},
        ylabel={$Y$},
        xtick={1,2,3,4},
        ytick={1,2,3,4},
        xmin=0.5, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=0.5, ymax=4.5,
        axis on top,
        point meta min=2,
        point meta max=8,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
        nodes near coords align={center},
    ]
        \addplot [
            matrix plot*,
            mesh/cols=4,
            point meta=explicit,
        ] table [meta=C] {
            x y C
            1 1 2
            1 2 3
            1 3 4
            1 4 5
            2 1 3
            2 2 4
            2 3 5
            2 4 6
            3 1 4
            3 2 5
            3 3 6
            3 4 7
            4 1 5
            4 2 6
            4 3 7
            4 4 8
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which produces the following heatmap

Now, I am considering the probability problem where a random variable Z=min(X,Y). In particular, for the case of Z=2 we have {(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(4,2)}.
How can I color the corresponding tiles for these five specific coordinates with a particular color (say red) while mainting the color of the remaining tiles as blue?
Edit: I am posting a figure below, to illustrate how the figure should like like based on my question


I suggest an alternative method here, utilizing tikz and expl3.
This can make it easier to add these highlight blocks.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% fill rectangles by a given coordinates list
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_nopar:Nn \__fill_block:nn {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {#2}
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}
  \int_step_inline:nnn {1}{\l_tmpa_int}{
    \def\tempCoor{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {##1}}
    \fill[#1, fill~ opacity=0.5, draw=black] \tempCoor++(0.5, 0.5) 
      rectangle ++(-1, -1);
  }
}
\newcommand{\fillBlock}{\__fill_block:nn}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% ==> coordinate system
\draw (0.5, 0.5) -- (0.5, 4.5);
\draw (0.5, 0.5) -- (4.5, 0.5);
\node at (2.5, -0.25) {$X$};
\node at (-0.25, 2.5) {$Y$};
\foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4}{
  \draw (\x, 0.5) -- (\x, 0.4) node[below] {\x};
  \draw (0.5, \x) -- (0.4, \x) node[left] {\x};
}

% ==> sum of 2 tosses
\foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4}{
  \foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4}{
    \fill[teal!\fpeval{(\x+\y)*12.5}] (\x, \y)++(0.5, 0.5) rectangle ++(-1, -1);
    \node at (\x, \y) {\fpeval{\x+\y}};
  }
}

% ==> hightlight coordinates type here
\fillBlock{red}{(2,2); (2,3); (2,4); (3,2); (4,2)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The Output:


You could manually add rectangles with tikz:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\colorlet{nblue}{blue}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.16}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap = {custom}{color(0)=(nblue!20) color(1)=(nblue!30) color(2)=(nblue!40) color(3)=(nblue!50) color(4)=(nblue!60) color(5)=(nblue!70) color(6)=(nblue!80) color(7)=(nblue!90) color(8)=(nblue)
        },
        xlabel={$X$},
        ylabel={$Y$},
        xtick={1,2,3,4},
        ytick={1,2,3,4},
        xmin=0.5, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=0.5, ymax=4.5,
        axis on top,
        point meta min=2,
        point meta max=8,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
        nodes near coords align={center},
    ]
        \addplot [
            matrix plot*,
            mesh/cols=4,
            point meta=explicit,
        ] table [meta=C] {
            x y C
            1 1 2
            1 2 3
            1 3 4
            1 4 5
            2 1 3
            2 2 4
            2 3 5
            2 4 6
            3 1 4
            3 2 5
            3 3 6
            3 4 7
            4 1 5
            4 2 6
            4 3 7
            4 4 8
        };
    \fill[red,draw=black,thick] (1.5,1.5) rectangle ++(1.5,0.5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


